# Specific record retrieval in Virtual Entity Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

I tried to set up virtual entity and yes I am able to show the record in CRM. But, I am not to open a specific record to see its details on form.[image: Virtual Entity Data in CRM]. Even in Web API we are handling single result method also, but not sure where we are missing. Please do the helpful on the same...[image: Error that I am getting when clicked on a specific record]

Comment: What does the log file says ?

Comment: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: new_person With Id = 6e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04 Does Not Exist. For testing purpose I have hard-coded the GUID values in my web application.

Comment: Retrieve is different from retrieve multiple... CRM can't retrieve a record with that ID. If you query your ODATA endpoint like /new_persons(6e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04) what does it return ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar here is my end point [link]https://trails2018.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/new_persons(6e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04). **error message** {"error":{"code":"0x80040217","message":"new_person With Id = 6e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04 Does Not Exist","innererror":{"message":"new_person With Id = 6e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04 Does Not Exist","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar when I run a query in browser I am able to get the result with below query [link]https://trails2018.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/new_persons **output** {"@odata.context":"https://trails2018.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#new_persons","value":[{"new_name":"Person1","new_personid":"6e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04","new_details":"Description of Person1","new_id":0},{"new_name":"Person2","new_personid":"7e5cbd9e-52e7-4182-9495-67cec7641c04","new_details":"Description of Person2","new_id":1}

Comment: Hi @OndrejSvejdar, it was single retrieve constructor issue in Web API. I have just changed that and its working fine. Earlier I was using like this **public SingleResult<Person> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)**. Now I have changed that to **public Person Get(Guid key)** and now its working. Thank you for the prompt response

Answer (score 0):

Prior posting the question here I was using a constructor for single retrieve like **public SingleResult Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)**. Now I have changed that to **public Person Get(Guid key)** and it's working fine.